# How can we add popup in FitNesse?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to add an `hyperlink` or a `button` in my `FitNesse page`.
On click of this link or button a popup window with some `HTML` content should open.

Please let me know if this is possible in `FitNesse`? If yes, how to achieve this?

I tried to search on `FitNesse` website but could not get information.

Comment: For popup in new window, please refer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545938/fitnesse-open-new-window-on-click-of-hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545938/fitnesse-open-new-window-on-click-of-hyperlink)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a link to a wiki page is easy: [just type the link](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupExternalLink), or use [`[[word or phrase][url]]`](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupAliasLink). But this will not open a pop-up. I don't know how to achieve that by just using the wiki.

In a Slim fixture's result you can return any HTML (sometimes you will have to surround it with `<div></div>`), so you can return `<a href="url" target="_blank">...</a>` and in the test result there will be a hyperlink that will open in a new tab...