# FitNesse - Open "new" window on click of hyperlink

Tags: fitnesse

Could anybody enlighten me as to how can one open "**new / separate**" window on click of hyperlink image in FitNesse page? (currently it opens in the same window).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add code like given below:

```
!-
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function openwindow() {
  newwindow=window.open('http://www.google.com'); // open some window
  if (window.focus) {
   newwindow.focus()
  }
  return false;
 }
</script>
-!
```

And below code for hyperlink:

```
!- <a href="" onclick="return openwindow()">click here to open new window in FitNesse</a> -!
```